# GPU issues post update

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, hdmi

Strange occurrences today using the updater, it got stuck in a loop of installing bunch of packages then would ask to update again but looked to be removing those same packages and then asking to install them again after. So to see if I could break the cycle I did a restart in between them specifically after the round that installed packages.
This is when display issues began after next boot and software updater saying all is well. I have two monitors hooked up to nvidia 2080 super, one is plugged into HDMI running at 1080p 60hz, the other is same monitor plugged into DP for 144hz. Now only the monitor plugged into HDMI is recognized at 1024x768 at 76hz and I am unable to change those settings even.
My next thought was to try a different driver so I went one at a time installing and checking to see if settings were changeable, then restarting, updating, checking settings again to no avail, on EVERY single driver option, servers included, same issues every time so I'm back to the latest driver also labelled (proprietary, tested) for now.
Some other strange occurrences post updates have been my usb logitech headset no longer works on startup, I have to unplug it and put it back in after startup to get it to show up in settings. I also have a 3rd party software called polychromatic to change my razer mouse settings and while the mouse works fine the software no longer recognizes it post update.
Seemingly a lot of shit broke today, big sad, life mash up :(

Answer (score 0):

Had the same bug, it was installing lots of different kernel versions (I think it was oem-oracle-nvidia-intel or something) and then removed them in the next step. I stopped that and after a reboot, the system upgrader tool popped up, and performed a correct and functioning kernel upgrade from 5.15.0-76 to 6.1.0-1015. (probably same as `sudo apt dist-upgrade`)

Then it was fine except that the Nvidia driver was not working anymore and the system running on built-in Intel graphics.

At the end, the command

```
sudo dkms autoinstall
```

fixed those problems too on my system. Maybe the Nvidia driver has to be reinstalled once.